# Conditional expectation on Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability

If we suppose that the two independent random variables $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_x)$ and $N \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_n)$ and that $S = X + N$, how would I work out the conditional expectation $E[X\mid S=s]$?

Comment: how is the dependence structure defined?

Comment: Are $X$ and  $N$ independent?

Comment: $X$ and $N$ are independent! Fixed my post.

Comment: Hint:  **if** $N$ and $X$ are jointly normal, then so are $X$ and $S$ jointly normal. Can you work out the parameters of $(X,S)$? Do you know the standard result for the conditional mean of $X$ given $S$ when $X$ and $S$ enjoy joint normality?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, I guess the parameters must be $\mu = (0,0)$ and $\Sigma = (\sigma_x^2,\sigma_x^2;\sigma_x^2;\sigma_x^2+\sigma_n^2)$? I do not know any of the standard results..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $X$ and $N$ are independent and normal, any combinations of $X$ and $N$ are normal. As any combination of $X+N$ and $\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N$ is also a combination of $X$ and $N$, that is, any combinations of $X+N$ and $\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N$ are normal, then $X+N$ and $\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N$ are jointly normal. Moreover, note that
\begin{align*}
E\bigg((X+N)\Big( \frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N\Big) \bigg) &= 0.
\end{align*}
Then $X+N$ and $\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N$ are independent. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
E\big( (X+N) \mid S\big) &= S,\\
E\bigg( \Big( \frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N\Big) \mid S\bigg) &= 0.
\end{align*}
Solving this system, we obtain that
\begin{align}
E(X\mid S) = \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_n^2}S.
\end{align}
In other words,
\begin{align}
E(X\mid S=s) = \frac{\sigma_x^2}{\sigma_x^2+\sigma_n^2}s.
\end{align}

Comment: how do you conclude that they are independent? For uncorrelation implying independence you need afaik that they are also jointly normal?!

Comment: @user190080: As $X$ and $N$ are normal, then any combinations of them are normal, and consequently, any combinations of $X+N$ and $\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N$ are normal. This implies the joint normality. Then uncorrelated implies independence.

Comment: @Gordon : If $X$ and $N$ are normal and independent, the certainly every linear combination of them is normal and every tuple of linear combnations of them is jointly normal.  But this hypothesis of independence, although it can be greatly weakened, cannot be simply dropped.  I can show you two random variables $X$ and $N$ that are normally distributed but for which some linear combinations are not normally distributed.  For example, let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and let $N=\pm X$, each with probability $1/2$, independently of $X$.  Then $\Pr(X+N=0)>0$, so $X+N$ is not normally distributed. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $X,N$ are jointly normal since they are independent, agreed. Therefore all linear transformations are normal, agreed. But now you want to conclude that for $S=X+N$ and $T=\frac{1}{\sigma_x^2}X - \frac{1}{\sigma_n^2}N$ and $\mathbf{E}(ST)=0$ it follows that $S$ and $T$ are independent, but this is only true if $S,T$ are also jointly normal, which is nowhere shown - do we agree here?

Comment: @user190080: any combination of $S$ and $T$ is also a combination of $X$ and $N$. That is, $S$ and $T$ are also jointly normal.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: See also my above comments -- any combination of $S$ and $T$ is also a combination of $X$ and $N$. That is, $S$ and $T$ are also jointly normal.

Comment: So your answer to the first comment was not correct as it stood.

Comment: I would answer that first comment as follows: Linear combinations of independent normals are normal, and linear combinations of $X+N$ and $aX+bN$ are linear combinations of $X$ and $N$; hence  linear combinations of $X+N$ and $aX+bN$ are lnormal; hence $X+N$ and $aX+bN$ are jointly normal. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: can you please be more specific which part in my answer is wrong? I have never said that uncorrelated implied independence. What I have said is that uncorrelated plus joint normality implies independence. Your above comment was what I said. Now I made it more explicit in my answer. By the way, as this is too basic, I think people understand anyways.

Comment: @Gordon : Quoting your comment above: "As X and N are normal, then any combinations of them are normal,"  But that doesn't follow.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: the independence is already assumed.

Comment: As it concerns me, I am convinced. I forgot that this is an "if and only if" relation between the linear transformations and jointly normal distributions, so your argumentation works, thanks to you two for pointing it out. .

Comment: @Gordon How does the product imply the below equations? E((X+N)*1) = 0 but E(X+N|S) = S and E(1|S) = 1? What am I missing here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/deriving-the-conditional-distributions-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution

Not as "clever" as Gordon's method above however.